# Is there a way to stop the glitching when I hover over a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am writing this program that requires me to change the formatting and the position of the text on mouseover() and return back to default properties on mouseout(). However when I hover over the text it starts glitching. Is there any way to stop that?

This is my full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Week6</title>
    <style>
        #p1{
            font-size: 2em;
            color: blue;
        }

        #div1{
            position: absolute;
            visibility: visible;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        h1{
            font-size: 3em;
            color: yellow;
            font-style: italic;
        }

        #div2{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            margin-top: -10px;
            left: 500px;
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">
        <h2>Move the cursor over the text to see it change.</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="div2">
        <h1>Move the cursor over the text to see it change.</h1>
    </div>
    
    
    
</body>
</html>

<script>
    let div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
    let div2 = document.getElementById("div2");

    div1.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
        div1.style.visibility = "hidden";
        div2.style.visibility = "visible";
        e.preventDefault();
    });


    div1.addEventListener('mouseout', ()=>{
        div1.style.visibility = "visible";
        div2.style.visibility = "hidden";
    })

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why did you want to make the element visible using JavaScript? It's simple while using CSS. I hope that code will help you a lot. Try to use CSS instead of JavaScript.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .div2 {
                visibility:hidden;
            }
                
            .div1:hover + .div2 {
                visibility:visible;
                color: red;
            }
            </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Display an Element on Hover</h2>
        <div class="div1">Hover over me.</div>
        <div class="div2">I am shown when someone hovers over the div above.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're right, but on mouseover I need to make the first div disappear and show the other div. Your code shows both divs at the same time on mouseover, which is not what I'm looking for. Besides that, even if this can be done without using JS, I am required to use JS for this program.